# AWS WaitCondition Wait for provision

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli

I am trying to learn Cloudformation im stuck with a senario where I need a second EC2 instance started after one EC2 is provisioned and good to go.

This is what i have in UserData of Instance one

```
"#!/bin/bash\n",
"#############################################################################################\n",
"sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes\n",
"sudo apt-get update\n",
"curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | sudo -E bash -\n",
"sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev python2.7 python-setuptools -y\n",
"#############################################################################################\n",
"Install Easy Install",
"#############################################################################################\n",
"easy_install https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples/aws-cfn-bootstrap-latest.tar.gz\n",
"#############################################################################################\n",
"#############################################################################################\n",
"GIT LFS Repo",
"#############################################################################################\n",
"curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/github/git-lfs/script.deb.sh | sudo bash\n",
"#############################################################################################\n",

"cfn-init",
"         --stack ",
{
"Ref": "AWS::StackName"
},
"         --resource UI",
"         --configsets InstallAndRun ",
"         --region ",
{
"Ref": "AWS::Region"
},
"\n",

"#############################################################################################\n",
"# Signal the status from cfn-init\n",
"cfn-signal -e 0 ",
"         --stack ",
{
"Ref": "AWS::StackName"
},
"         --resource UI",
"         --region ",
{
"Ref": "AWS::Region"
},
" ",
{
"Ref": "WaitHandleUIConfig"
},
"\n"
```

I have a WaitCondition , which i think is whats used to do this

```
 "WaitHandleUIConfig" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::CloudFormation::WaitConditionHandle",
      "Properties" : {}
    },

    "WaitConditionUIConfig" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::CloudFormation::WaitCondition",
      "DependsOn" : "UI",
      "Properties" : {
        "Handle" : { "Ref" : "WaitHandleUIConfig" },
        "Timeout" : "500"
      }
    }
```

In the Instance i use the DependsOn in the second instance to wait for first instance.

```
"Service": {
  "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
  "Properties": {
  },
  "Metadata": {
    "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
      "id": "1ba546d0-2bad-4b68-af47-6e35159290ca"
    },
  },
  "DependsOn":"WaitConditionUIConfig"
}
```

this isnt working. I keep getting the error

**WaitCondition timed out. Received 0 conditions when expecting 1**

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put quotes around the Handle

Change this

```
" ",
{
"Ref": "WaitHandleUIConfig"
},
"\n"
```

to this

```
" \"",
{
"Ref": "WaitHandleUIConfig"
},
"\"\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `--stack`, `--resource` and `--region` from your [`cfn-signal`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-signal.html) command. These are only used when 'resource signaling', not when signaling using a Wait Condition Handle. (You might also need to add an `--id` option, but the documentation says this is not required.)

For further debugging, examine the `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` file on the EC2 instance to view any further cloud-init errors that might fail to successfully send the signal to your wait condition.

You might also want to comment and newline the descriptions `"Install Easy Install",` and `"GIT LFS Repo",`, e.g., `"# Install Easy Install\n",`, these syntax issues shouldn't cause your script to fail but will output 'command not found' errors to appear in your log.